# Grid Search builds models with different parameters (h2o in R) yields identical performance - why?

Tags: r, h2o, grid-search, gbm

Code and results below. How is this possible? MSEs are identical with vastly different parameters.

```
hyper_params <- list(
        ntrees = c(5000, 7000, 10000),
        max_depth = c(15,18,21,24,27),
        min_rows = c(5,7,10,13,16),
        learn_rate = c(0.01,0.03,0.05,0.1),
        col_sample_rate_per_tree = c(0.3,0.5,0.7,0.85),
        min_split_improvement = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70))

  search_criteria = list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete",
                         #stopping_rounds = 3,
                         max_models = num_models)#,
                         #stopping_tolerance=1e-3
  grid <- h2o.grid(
    algorithm = "gbm",
    grid_id = "grid",
    training_frame = train,
    # validation_frame = valid,
    x = independent_variables,
    y="NSP",
    stopping_metric="MSE",
    hyper_params = hyper_params,
    search_criteria = search_criteria,
    nfolds = 5,
    fold_assignment = "Modulo",
    keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE)

Hyper-Parameter Search Summary: ordered by increasing mse
   col_sample_rate_per_tree learn_rate max_depth min_rows min_split_improvement ntrees     model_ids                 mse
1                       0.5       0.01        24      5.0                  60.0   7000  grid_model_2 0.36927908175912655
2                      0.85       0.01        18      5.0                  40.0   5000  grid_model_6 0.36927908175912655
3                       0.3        0.1        24     13.0                  30.0   7000 grid_model_11 0.36927908175912655
4                      0.85       0.03        24     10.0                  50.0   5000  grid_model_4 0.36927908175912655
5                       0.5       0.01        21      5.0                  30.0   7000  grid_model_9 0.36927908175912655
6                      0.85        0.1        24     10.0                  70.0   5000 grid_model_13 0.36927908175912655
7                       0.7        0.1        15     13.0                  10.0  10000 grid_model_14 0.36927908175912655
8                       0.3       0.05        27     13.0                  20.0   7000  grid_model_5 0.36927908175912655
9                      0.85       0.05        27     13.0                  70.0   7000  grid_model_0 0.36927908175912655
10                      0.7       0.05        24     13.0                  60.0   5000  grid_model_7 0.36927908175912655
11                     0.85       0.05        21      7.0                  20.0  10000  grid_model_8 0.36927908175912655
12                      0.5       0.01        15      7.0                  20.0  10000 grid_model_10 0.36927908175912655
13                      0.3       0.01        18      7.0                  30.0   7000  grid_model_1 0.36927908175912655
14                      0.5       0.03        21     13.0                  10.0   5000 grid_model_12 0.36927908175912655
15                     0.85       0.01        21      7.0                  40.0   5000  grid_model_3 0.36927908175912655
```

Any and all guidance is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example?  For example, using the iris dataset or some other publicly available dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your data is such that there is only way to learn it.

As a concrete example, if you set max_depth to 18, and another tree to max_depth to 24, but you only have a single entry in `independent_variables`, then it is most likely only going to make trees of depth 1 or 2 in each case. So the different hyper parameter will make no difference.

If you cannot give the data that reproduces it, it would be interesting to output the summary of a default model (not using a grid, not using any particular parameters). Also, show the column types, and `nrow(train)`. (If you have the wrong column types it could explain what you see.)